Replace duplicate values across columns of CSV file
I have a headerless CSV file that is sorted on the first column. When the 2nd and 3rd columns are identical, I want to "collapse" them into one - i.e. leave the last column empty. In other words, this:
0000001,11111,66666
0000002,12121,22222
0000003,33333,33333
0000004,74747,44444
0000005,12345,12345

...becomes this:
0000001,11111,66666
0000002,12121,22222
0000003,33333,
0000004,74747,44444
0000005,12345,

I've tried various permutations of grep and cut but can't get anything to work - the closest I've come is cut -c 8-19 file.csv, which just isolates the 2nd and 3rd columns. I have a feeling needing to do this across columns and needing to delete the value instead of the whole line makes this complicated enough to require awk or sed, and I don't know enough about either to know how to approach it.

can you confirm that you really do want to add a 4th field to those lines where the 2nd field == 3rd field? you'll now have a) some lines with 3 fields and b) some lines with 4 fields

@markp-fuso You seem to be right - it's not easily visible from the output files but awk 'length > 16' "file.csv" | cut -d"," -f4 gives me a lot of blanks when it should produce nothing because a 4th column shouldn't exist. What's this caused by and how would it be fixed?

the comma is a delimiter so if you add a comma then you're adding a new column; in your description you state replace the last column with a comma which is another way of saying 'clear out the 3rd column and add a 4th (empty) column'; assuming you really want to maintain 3 columns in all lines then what you really want to do is remove the last column (ie, set the last column to a blank); your last line of expected output would then change from 0000005,12345,, (2 trailing commas) to 0000005,12345, (1 trailing comma)

how to fix - don't add a new comma; for anubhava's answer change $3=OFS to $3=""; for ssetltaH's answer remove the very last comma from the sed script (ie, \2/\1,/ becomes \2/\1/)

@markp-fuso Unfortunately I still get the same blank lines from that awk/cut command whether there's 2,1 or no trailing commas on the line. Is this expected behaviour?

@HashimAziz, just check to be assure once that you don't have carriage returns in your file. Try using cat -vet Input_file? And see if see any control M there.

cut -d"," -f4 is going to print an empty line if a) there is no 4th field or b) if the 4th field is empty; try awk -F, '{print NF}' file.csv to show the number of comma-delimited fields for each line of input (NF==number_of_fields)

@RavinderSingh13 Unfortunately not, the editor showed the file has LF endings set and I also ran dos2unix on the file for good measure.

@markp-fuso That did it, awk -F, '{print NF}' | sort -u shows only adding 1 trailing comma to those lines produces a single consistent number of fields. Thanks for spotting this and for your help solving it, feel free to add all your comments into an answer and I'll upvote it - this was caused by my faulty assumption that ,, would equal 1 empty column.

keep in mind that awk -F, '{print NF}' will generate incorrect values if your data fields also contain commas and/or embedded linefeeds (the data fields are typically wrapped in double quotes in this case) - in such a case -F, is insufficient for defining a field; not an issue for this particular set of data but something to keep in mind if/when you find yourself dealing with a more complicated csv format

no need for me to move my comments to an answer since the comments don't really 'answer' the original question; you're welcome to update the question with an addendum (as opposed to modifying the question which would have the effect of invalidating the answers you've already received)

@markp-fuso Instead of adding an edit that no-one is likely to read I just updated the question along with (most of) the answers, so they're still consistent with each other and do what someone coming across the question through Google would likely want, without having to read through a wall of question text or comments to figure out what happened.

Using sed
$ sed -E 's/([^,]*,([^,]*),)\2/\1/' input_file
0000001,11111,66666
0000002,12121,22222
0000003,33333,
0000004,74747,44444
0000005,12345,


Damn that was fast! Can't say I understand how that regex works, but it definitely does. Can confirm both answers produce identical output files, upvoted both and accepted this one purely because it was the first.

Works for GNU sed but not for BSD sed (e.g. on Mac OS X).

You could remove the leading [^,]*, it's not doing anything useful.

This would fail with input like 0000003,33333,333334 - you should really add an end of string anchor $ to the end of the regexp.

This awk(with any distro) should work for you:
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $2 == $3 {$3=""} 1' file

0000001,11111,66666
0000002,12121,22222
0000003,33333,
0000004,74747,44444
0000005,12345,


In GNU awk with your shown samples please try following code. Using match function with regex
(^[^,]+,)([^,]+)(,)([^,]+)(.*$) and using it's capability to save matched values into capturing groups which are getting used for later check and print as per requirement.
awk '
match($0,/(^[^,]+,)([^,]+)(,)([^,]+)(.*$)/,arr){
  if(arr[2]==arr[4]){ arr[4]=arr[3] }
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[4]
}
' Input_file


Just a heads up, in order to keep this answer consistent with the others and attracting the upvotes it deserves you may want to update the answer to reflect that I actually needed 1 trailing comma instead of 2, I edited the others but didn't want to risk doing the same to yours since I don't fully understand it.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/(,.*)\1$/\1,/' file

Pattern match the second and third columns and replace by the second column.

Yes, turns out I only needed one comma, have edited all the answers accordingly.

@HashimAziz Probably also need to edit the output to match, in that case.

This would fail with input like 0000003,33333,333334 - you should really add an end of string anchor $ to the end of the regexp.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
0000001,11111,66666
0000002,12121,22222
0000003,33333,33333
0000004,74747,44444
0000005,12345,12345

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$2==$3?"":$3}' file.txt

gives output
0000001,11111,66666
0000002,12121,22222
0000003,33333,
0000004,74747,44444
0000005,12345,

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that comma is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS), then I compose line using so-called ternary operator with condition being 2nd field is equal 3rd field, value if true being empty string and value if false being 3rd field content.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)
